# Getting failed to open device error for swissranger even after udev rules change

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm attempting to set up a swissranger TOF camera in ROS to be used in RVIZ. I'm fairly new to ROS and have been working through the tutorials. I have installed ROS using the tutorials on the site on a clean Ubuntu installation, single user machine, running 12.04. The ROS installation is Fuerte.

I have followed the instructions on the ros.org tutorial

as well as here some instructions I found on youBot.

And have done some digging but, I gotta admit, I am totally lost. I am able to run the libMesaSRTester if I run 'sudo /usr/bin/libMesaSRTester' but it does not run properly if it is not run with sudo. I changed the udev rules as recommended. Here's the current version of my 46-mesa.rules file:

```
BUS!="usb", SUBSYSTEM!=="usb_device", ACTION!="add", GOTO="kcontrol_rules_end"

#Swissranger SR3k(old),SR3k,SR4k
SYSFS{idVendor}=="0852", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0074", MODE="666", GROUP="usb"
SYSFS{idVendor}=="1ad2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0074", MODE="666", GROUP="usb"
SYSFS{idVendor}=="1ad2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0075", MODE="666", GROUP="usb"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0852", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0074", MODE="660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1ad2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0074", MODE="660", GROUP="plugdev"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", SYSFS{idVendor}=="1ad2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0075", MODE="660", GROUP="plugdev"

LABEL="kcontrol_rules_end"
```

I have also added myself to the usb group as recommended at the youBot page.

On running rosrun swissranger_camera swissranger_camera I get the following error:

```
usb_set_debug: Setting debugging level to 255 (on)
usb_os_find_busses: Found 004
usb_os_find_busses: Found 003
usb_os_find_busses: Found 002
usb_os_find_busses: Found 001
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 004
skipping descriptor 0x30
skipped 1 class/vendor specific endpoint descriptors
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 003
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 008 on 002
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 007 on 002
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 006 on 002
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 002 on 002
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 002
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 004 on 001
skipping descriptor 0xB
skipped 1 class/vendor specific endpoint descriptors
skipped 6 class/vendor specific interface descriptors
skipping descriptor 0x25
skipped 1 class/vendor specific endpoint descriptors
skipped 10 class/vendor specific interface descriptors
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 003 on 001
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 002 on 001
usb_os_find_devices: couldn't get connect info
usb_os_find_devices: Found 001 on 001
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
error obtaining child information: Operation not permitted
USB error: could not set config 1: Operation not permitted
usb_set_debug: Setting debugging level to 0 (off)
[ERROR] [1356223678.742940718]: Exception thrown while connecting to the camera: [SR::open]: Failed to open device!
```

Surely the problem is in rights but I just can't figure out what I've gotten wrong on my end. Any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50976/getting-failed-to-open-device-error-for-swissranger-even-after-udev-rules-change/) by [Nahkki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3835/nahkki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chyphen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3555/chyphen/) on 2013-08-02**:
Did you finally solve the problem?  I ran into similar problems as you had.   Udev rules(46-mesa.rules) were set as recommended.  Added my self to usb group.  Got the error "Exception thrown while connecting to the camera: [SR::open]: Failed to open device!".   Did "sudo chmod -R a+rwx /dev/bus/usb" as suggested by rasmusan, then everything seemed to be ok as long as SR-3000 was on and the USB cable was connected.  However, if SR-3000 was powered off then powered on or the USB cable was disconnected then reconnected, then the error appeared, and "sudo chmod -R a+rwx /dev/bus/usb" was needed to get things going.  I am wondering if there is any permanent solution to fix the permission issue.  Thanks, CC

**Comment by [Nahkki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3835/nahkki/) on 2013-08-02**:
My permanent solution is pretty gross to be honest. I gave the user who is running the pipeline god rights. Given the extremely limited environment our system is running in it works ok, but it may not be a viable solution for anyone else.

**Comment by [chyphen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3555/chyphen/) on 2013-08-05**:
Can you be more specific on "god' rights?  I added myself to usb group, it didn't work without doing "sudo chmod -R a+rwx /dev/bus/usb" whenever SR-3000 was powered on or a USB cable was reconnected", Then I added myself to root group, and it didn't work, either.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got this error too. The problem for me was, that the usb devices could only be accessed by root. The fix was:

sudo chmod -R a+rwx /dev/bus/usb

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04. Hope this can help.

---

Originally posted by [rasmusan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4783/rasmusan/) with karma: 36 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [funas1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4204/funas1/) on 2013-05-15**:
This worked for me as well, I had the same problem. Thank you!

**Comment by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on 2013-07-03**:
@ the users of swissranger_camera, I have some questions. Are you guys running the "swissranger_camera" ROS package and using "PCL" from ROS as well? I noticed that the pointcloud message publish by "swissranger_camera" no longer supports by PCL. How did you guys solve the problem?

**Comment by [chyphen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3555/chyphen/) on 2013-08-01**:
I got the same error, and the error was "temporarily" fixed by adding  sudo chmod -R a+rwx /dev/bus/usb as suggested.  However, I need to do it every time SR-3000 is turned back on or the USB cable is re-plugged in.  Is there a permanent fix?  I am running Ubuntu 12.04 + ROS fuerte on a 32-bit PC.

Thanks,
CC